# Android App Doesn't Recognize Changes Made

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android app and for some reason even after I make changes to the code that should institute some change, the changes aren't shown when I run the app on my phone. For example, I had a TextView print something different, but the app when run still prints what was there before the change. I did a Project Clean, saved my changes, etc. Any ideas why this can be happening? I can post code if necessary, but I figured this is a pretty generic question and is probably not something code-related. THanks!

Comment: What IDE are you using, and are you publishing APK files to install on your phone, or is your IDE installing for you?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I am just running the app on my phone through a USB cable!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling pervious installation of the app?

Comment: I will try that now!

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday. The changes I made to image files in my res folders were not showing in the app on my test device. Completely uninstalling the app from the device and cleaning the project under the build menu fixed the problem.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!